# Matplotlib specific representation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am studying the influence of diverse factors on the distribution of bikes throughout a bike- sharing system called Velib in paris. I have 1222 bike stations with their occupation rate, their latitude and their longitude. I would like to make a map like this : 
(http://images.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fscipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org%2F_images%2Fgriddataexample1.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwizardforcel.gitbooks.io%2Fscipy-cookbook-en%2Fcontent%2F37.html&h=288&w=432&tbnid=j0EtJS7s1utbYM%3A&docid=KQV-DInQ9QIq2M&ei=L2ADWJqUJ8L9aemiiYAJ&tbm=isch&client=safari&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=1229&page=13&start=324&ndsp=31&ved=0ahUKEwja57uTmN_PAhXCfhoKHWlRApA4rAIQMwg0KDEwMQ&bih=739&biw=1438) However i can't figure out a way to do it using marplotlib. For now i have this code but it is irrelevant to what i am trying to show:

```
for k in range(number gf bike stations):
```

T(k)/Tt is (occupation rate/average occupation rate) and R_0 is a list with all the data

```
if T(k)/Tt>1.5:      (if the occupation ratio is >1.5, i scatter a green dot and so on)
    ax.scatter(R_0[k]['position']['lng'],R_0[k]['position']['lat'], color='g', s=10)       
elif T(k)/Tt>1:      (yellow dot)
    ax.scatter(R_0[k]['position']['lng'],R_0[k]['position']['lat'], color='y', s=10)
elif T(k)/Tt>0.5:    (red dot)
    ax.scatter(R_0[k]['position']['lng'],R_0[k]['position']['lat'], color='r', s=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.contour(x, y, z)
matplotlib.pyplot.contourf(x, y, z)
```

with arguments x - latitude, y - longitude and z - occupation rate.